# merging 3 dataframes on condition

Tags: pandas

i have a dataframe df

```
id   value
1    100
2    200
3    500
4    600
5    700
6    800
```

i have another dataframe df2

```
c_id    flag
2       Y
3       Y 
5       Y
```

Similarly df3

```
c_id    flag
1       N
3       Y 
4       Y
```

i want to merge these 3 dataframes and create a column in df
 such that my df looks like:

```
id   value  flag
1    100     N
2    200     Y
3    500     Y
4    600     Y
5    700     Y
6    800     nan
```

I DON'T WANT TO USE df2 and df3 concatenation

for eg(

```
final = pd.concat([df2,df3],ignore_index=False)
final.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

i don't want to use this method, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.merge`, between `df` and combined `df2+df3`

```
In [1150]: df.merge(df2.append(df3), left_on=['id'], right_on=['c_id'], how='left')
Out[1150]:
   id  value  c_id flag
0   1    100   1.0    N
1   2    200   2.0    Y
2   3    500   3.0    Y
3   3    500   3.0    Y
4   4    600   4.0    Y
5   5    700   5.0    Y
6   6    800   NaN  NaN
```

Details

```
In [1151]: df2.append(df3)
Out[1151]:
   c_id flag
0     2    Y
1     3    Y
2     5    Y
0     1    N
1     3    Y
2     4    Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` you could

```
In [1140]: df.assign(flag=df.id.map(
                 df2.set_index('c_id')['flag'].combine_first(
                     df3.set_index('c_id')['flag']))
                 )
Out[1140]:
   id  value flag
0   1    100    N
1   2    200    Y
2   3    500    Y
3   4    600    Y
4   5    700    Y
5   6    800  NaN
```

Let me explain, using `set_index` and `combine_first` create a `mapping` for `id` and `flag`

```
In [1141]: mapping = df2.set_index('c_id')['flag'].combine_first(
                         df3.set_index('c_id')['flag'])

In [1142]: mapping
Out[1142]:
c_id
1    N
2    Y
3    Y
4    Y
5    Y
Name: flag, dtype: object

In [1143]: df.assign(flag=df.id.map(mapping))
Out[1143]:
   id  value flag
0   1    100    N
1   2    200    Y
2   3    500    Y
3   4    600    Y
4   5    700    Y
5   6    800  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge on both df2 and df3

```
df= pd.merge(pd.merge(df,df2,on='ID',how='left'),df3,on='ID',how='left')
```

Fill nulls

```
df['ID'] =df['ID_y'].fillna(df['ID_x']
```

Delete the columns

```
del df['ID_y']; del df['ID_x']
```

Or you could just append,

```
df4 = df2.append(df3)
pd.merge(df,df4,how='left',on='ID')
```